# Shape drawn by cycloids

Tags: geometry, cycloid

So, I'm not a maths wizard. My knowledge of it runs up to what you'd expect to find in your common core algebra 2 class.
I'm trying to describe a shape. I've seen it somewhere, can't say when or where. The shape is formed by **two circles**, a **central circle** and another circle **tangential** to the central circle with a radius/diameter a whole number fraction of the central circle's. The tangential circle "rolls" around the perimeter of the central circle, drawing out a **cycloid** from the first point of tangentiality, ending where it began. The resulting cycloids drawn outside the perimeter of the central circle forms the kind of shape I am trying to describe.
The shape is lobed. Two lobes, three, eight, whatever, all dependent on the ratio of the central circle to the tangential circle's diameter/radius.
If there is no name for these kinds of shapes, that is okay, I'm really just trying to find a reference to it in some way so I have a means to describe it without having to explicitly define it.
I have scoured Wikipedia articles and Google Images looking for some signs of it, mostly with the keyword "cycloids," but to no avail. To be quite truthfully frank with you, I'm not so certain it has to do with cycloids—initially, I thought it had something to do with the mandelbrot set. This really isn't my field.

Question: **What is the name of this shape, *or* what is a viable, namely reference to whatever it is that I'm attempting to describe?**

Comment: Sounds like an [epicycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epicycloid)

Comment: Boom. That's the one.

Comment: Also lookup [Centered trochoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centered_trochoid).

Comment: Huh, now I don't so much wonder why I thought of the mandelbrot set at first. When both radii are equal, it pretty much draws that shape. Anyway, thank you. Post your comment as an answer so we can forget this nonsense haha

Answer (score 1):

[image: [Epicycloids]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL55H.jpg)

> is a plane curveproduced by tracing the path of a chosen point on the circumference of a circle—called an epicycle—which rolls without slipping around a fixed circle